# How to allow user to access with any emailadress in firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to implement the folowing function:

1. Registration trough my app with every possible emailadress with the
   following format e.g. xx@xx.com, xx.xx@x-xx.de, xx-xx@xx-xx.com...

I enabled Email/password Auth in Firebase and have the following code to create the user:

```
     @IBAction func createButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    view.endEditing(true)

    guard let image = selectedImage else { return }
    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) else { return }
    ProgressHUD.show("Lade", interaction: false)

    if manager.location != nil {
        // Aktuellen Standort laden
        let userLat = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "current_latitude") as! String
        let userLong = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "current_longitude") as! String

        AuthService.createUser(username: usernameTextfield.text!, email: emailtextfield.text!, password: passwortTextField.text!, imageData: imageData, onSuccess: {

            let location:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLat)!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLong)!))
            // Update aktuellen Standort
            LocationApi.shared.locationManager(self.manager, didUpdateLocations: [location])

            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Profil wurde erstellt")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerSegue", sender: nil)
        }) { (error) in
            ProgressHUD.showError("User konnte nicht erstellt werden")
        }
    } else {
        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegistrationToErrorVc", sender: nil)
    }


}

    // Account erstellen
static func createUser(username: String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ error: String?) -> Void) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (data, error) in
        if let err = error {
            onError(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        // User erfolgreich erstellt
        guard let uid = data?.user.uid else { return }
        self.uploadUserData(uid: uid, username: username, email: email, imageData: imageData, onSuccess: onSuccess)
    }
}





static func uploadUserData(uid: String, username: String, email: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {


    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_image").child(uid)

    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }

    storageRef.downloadURL(completion:  { (url, error) in
        if  error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let profilImageURL = url?.absoluteString


        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
        ref.setValue(["uid": uid, "username" : username,"username_lowercase": username.lowercased(),"radius": "20", "email" : email, "profileImageURL": profilImageURL ?? "Kein Bild vorhanden"])
    })
     onSuccess()
    }
}
```

When i add a User, for example p.m@xx-xx.com, the user will be created in my Authentifiacation but there ist no entry in my database. I also get no specific error message for this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to set some breakpoints; maybe your ref.setValue doesn't get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`storageRef.putData` and `storageRef.downloadURL` are both asynchronous functions. My guess to why your setValue isn't executing is because `storageRef.downloadURL` is returning an error since `storageRef.putData` hasn't actually uploaded the data yet.

I would suggest retrieving the URL of the upload through the `metaData` like so:

```
guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75) else { return }
let metaData = StorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { metaData, error in
    if error == nil, metaData != nil {
        // upload was successful
        if let url = metaData?.downloadURL() {
            ref.setValue(["uid": uid, "username" : username,"username_lowercase": username.lowercased(),"radius": "20", "email" : email, "profileImageURL": url ?? "Kein Bild vorhanden"])
            onSuccess()
        } else {
            onSuccess()
        }
    } else {
        // error handle - your completion handler should really return a bool so you know if the upload was successful or not
        onSuccess()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem is, for example on [at]gmail.com email endings, the data will be uploaded. But when i try with a other email e.g. [at]x-xx.com, the data will be not uploaded. The result is, that my ref.setValue will execute the upload just sometimes.

Comment: I just tested creating an account on my app with the email `test@test-test.com` and it worked fine - so domains with are dash in the middle are supported by Firebase Authentication (the user object was also set in the database BTW). I would suggest trying to do you photo upload in a similar manner to mine, where you use the `metadata` to get the URL rather than `storageRef.downloadURL`. If you are not handling asynchronous functions properly then code will only appear to work sometimes.

Comment: okay I now know the problem. Try it with x.x@x-xx.com or x-x@x-xx.com that doesn't work in my code.

Comment: I was able to create an account with the email `h.h@h-h.com` and `x-x@x-xx.com` I believe those are valid emails that Firebase supports.

Comment: `image` will be the `UIImage` from the photo picker. You probably don't have the variables named the same way I do but you will need to slightly adjust your code to work with mine.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you create a answer I will accept it!

Comment: No problem! The answer from this comment thread is mine if you would like to accept it that would be amazing!